# Generating XPS document from a Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, toolbar, xpsdocument, xps-generation

I want to capture the html content in web browser and print to XPS Document. I am using a Windows application to do it since it is used in IE toolbar. Is there a way to capture the httpwebrequest to read the content of the webpage to to a FixedDocument object or other through other ways so that it can be converted to an XPSDocument?

Answer (score 1):

Print it via the Microsoft XPS Document Writer (MXDW; the XPS virtual printer) to an XPS file?

Comment: Yes. I can get the document stream through a webbrowser control, but how can i convert it to XPS format?